# After loading an object, on updating, identifier of an instance of x was altered from y to z is thrown

Tags: hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I am trying to read the object from the database and make an update.
Consider this Bi-directional mapping

```
STUDENT    --->   COURSES  
One               Many
```

***hbm.xml's:***
Student.hbm.xml:

```
<set name="courses" table="COURSES" inverse="false" >
            <key>
                <column name="STUDENT_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many  class="Courses" />
</set>
```

Courses.hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one name="student" class="Student" >
        <column name="STUDENT_ID" />
</many-to-one>
```

***Java Code:***

```
        Session session = Utility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Student student = (Student)session.get(Student.class, 1);

        Courses course = new Courses();
        course.setPriceOpen(new Float("1.2"));
        course.setPriceClose(new Float("1.1"));
        course.setPrceChange(new Float("10.0"));
        course.setDate(new Date());

        course.setStudent(student);        
        student.getCourses().add(course);

        session.save(course);
        session.update(student);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

After loading an ***Student*** object from the database, I am trying to add a ***new Course*** to ***that loaded Student instance***.
However, i do get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
identifier of an instance of Course was altered from 1 to 0.
```

Any suggestions on how will I update that Student instance, so that this instance of Student will now have 2 courses assigned to it.

Comment: How did you define identity column in HBM?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179166/hibernate-how-to-fix-identifier-of-an-instance-altered-from-x-to-y

Comment: You dont need to save course. Just update the student. and in hbm file set cascade=update for course. Let me know if that works