# How to update a @ManyToOne relationship with Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Data REST with JPA. I have a User entity that has a many to one relationship with another called AccountStatus modeled in a separate RDBMS table. The JSON representation looks like this:

```
{
   "id": "123"
   "username": "user1",
   "accountStatus": {
     "id": "1",
     "status": "Active"
   }
}
```

The relationship in the User entity is:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_state")
@Getter @Setter private AccountState accountState;
```

Now I try to change the account status using a PATCH request on /users/123 and the payload:

```
{"accountState":{"id":0}}
```

But I get an error:

```
 "identifier of an instance of com.domain.account.AccountState was
  altered from 1 to 0; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
  identifier of an instance of com.domain.account.AccountState was
 altered from 1 to 0"
```

I also tried to use @HandleBeforeSave/@HandleBeforeLinkSave to fetch the new AccountState from the repository and replace user.accountStatus with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: How to fix "identifier of an instance altered from X to Y"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179166/hibernate-how-to-fix-identifier-of-an-instance-altered-from-x-to-y)

Comment: @Makoto, I think the other question is about changing the PK of an owning entity, my issue is about changing a child relationship where no cascading is defined between User and AccountState.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It really depends if you have an exported repository for `AccountState`. If you do you can update your account state with a `PATCH` against `/users/{id}`:

```
{
    "accountState": "http://localhost:8080/accountStates/2"
}
```

So you are using the URI of your account state to reference the resource to assign

Comment: Hey Mathias, I am having the same problem but due to various reasons the 'accountState' in our instance is not exported. Is there a way to do it without it exported?

Comment: @pasquers I don't think so - I think you would have to create a custom controller for the update and add a link to that to your owning resource