# HibernateException: identifier of an instance was altered from Alert@62794582 to Alert@c82ad22

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb, usertype

I am implementing persistence API using Hibernate JPA.
 
I am using PostgreSQL 10.4 and storing data as JSONB.
 
I am sharing my implementation of Hibernate and Entity, please point why i am getting below exception.

I following this wonderful article to implement custom UserType as Hibernate does not support PostgreSQL JSONB datatype:
 
https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/

I was able to create the Entity mappings and do a simple Select query and print the value assigned to the mapping.

The issue is when i perform a commit operation on the transaction, i get the below exception:

> 22:42:35.218 [main] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - rollback()
>   called on an inactive transaction Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:86)
>     at com.postgres.main.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:41) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   **org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of
>   com.postgres.model.Alert was altered from
>   com.postgres.model.Alert@62794582 to com.postgres.model.Alert@c82ad22**
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>     at
>   **org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:67)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of
>   an instance of com.postgres.model.Alert was altered from
>   com.postgres.model.Alert@62794582 to com.postgres.model.Alert@c82ad22**
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:64)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
>     ... 1 more

I also followed following post where folks shared how they fixed the issue, but it did not help me: 
 
[Hibernate: How to fix "identifier of an instance altered from X to Y"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179166/hibernate-how-to-fix-identifier-of-an-instance-altered-from-x-to-y/27212970)

This is the Alert Entity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Alert.class)
@Table(name = "alert")
public class Alert implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "historyid")
    private Character historyId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tenantname")
    private Character tenantName;

    @Column(name = "data")
    @Type(type = "AlertJsonUserType")
    private AlertJson alertJson;

    public Character getHistoryId() {
        return historyId;
    }

    public void setHistoryId(Character historyId) {
        this.historyId = historyId;
    }

    public Character getTenantName() {
        return tenantName;
    }

    public void setTenantName(Character tenantName) {
        this.tenantName = tenantName;
    }

    public AlertJson getAlertJson() {
        return alertJson;
    }

    public void setAlertJson(AlertJson alertJson) {
        this.alertJson = alertJson;
    }
}
```

This is the Entity for the JSONB element in the Alert Entity

```
public class AlertJson implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("DeviceId")
    private String deviceId;

    @JsonProperty("TenantName")
    private String tenantName;

    @JsonProperty("FocusPointId")
    private List<FocusPointId> focusPointId;

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public String getTenantName() {
        return tenantName;
    }

    public void setTenantName(String tenantName) {
        this.tenantName = tenantName;
    }

    public List<FocusPointId> getFocusPointId() {
        return focusPointId;
    }

    public void setFocusPointId(List<FocusPointId> focusPointId) {
        this.focusPointId = focusPointId;
    }
}

class FocusPointId
{
    @JsonProperty("PartNumber")
    private String partNumber;

    @JsonProperty("SerialNumber")
    private String serialNumber;

    public String getPartNumber() {
        return partNumber;
    }

    public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
    }

    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
  }
```

Below is the snippet of the main() where i am creating a EntityManager instance and issuing a query

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-persistence-unit");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Query alertQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM \"A.01\".\"Alert\" where tenantname = 'TestUser-152'", Alert.class);
    List<Alert> alertList = alertQuery.getResultList();

    for(Alert jsonElement : alertList)
    {
        System.out.println("======> "+"Device: " + jsonElement.getAlertJson().getDeviceId() + " TenantName: " +jsonElement.getAlertJson().getTenantName());
    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    emf.close();
}
```

Below is the describe table and the constraints.
PK is both historyid and tenantname.

[image: Table Describe]

[image: Table Constraints]

Comment: seems like you are reassigning id somewhere in your code and hence hibernate is rejecting this new update of Id. Try debugging your code and observe the changes in id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this problem because you wrongly use `IdClass` annotation, you should create a separate class `AlertId` for example that will have to fields from your composed PK, and this class should be used as parameter for `IdClass` annotation

Comment: Thank you, that helped. It fixed the earlier issue but i am getting the new exception.

Comment: This issue is resolved, thanks. With your input, i followed this post to handle two composite keys in JPA and it worked: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/